# Android remote service, how to do a scheduled task?

Tags: android, android-service

I am writing an application which has a remote service running and I need to do a GPS task every 15 minutes.

Will a handler `postDelayed` functionality guarantee that it will trigger every 15 minutes without keeping the service in the foreground?

If not, is there some other way to do this ?

(i do not want to keep in foreground as I guess it might result in a lot of power consumption)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlarmManager` to trigger a service in ever 15 minutes.The service will do the gps things for you.After finishing the task you can stop the service.It will guarantee that your service will be started at every 15 minutes and moreover service will stops after fulfilling its purpose

Comment: You are right but i already have the service running in the background throughout. I guess the handler will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
*Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {
            //write code here you want to execute in every 15 minutes

        }
        }, new Date(), 900000);*
```